Mi aplicacion Java no ejecuta despues de compilada
He creado una aplicacion Java With Maven, usando Netbeans. Todo funciona perfecto, la app no me da errores cuando la ejecuto desde el IDE. Sin embargo, cuando hago el build e intento ejecutar el .jar, no se muestra absolutamente nada en pantalla (la aplicacion tiene interfaz gráfica). Esta es la configuracion del POM.XML de la app:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>SecureTouch</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ZKFinger</groupId>
            <artifactId>library</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>JDBC</groupId>
            <artifactId>JDBC</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.external</groupId>
            <artifactId>AbsoluteLayout</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE210</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okio</groupId>
            <artifactId>okio</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>1</groupId>
            <artifactId>1</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <exec.mainClass>com.mycompany.alixsecuretouch.AlixSecureTouch</exec.mainClass>
    </properties>
</project>


Tienes que debugar, no vale "mirar el pom". Añade un logger a tu aplicación y haz que imprima los petes en un archivo .txt que luego puedas leer. Si no, es imposible saber qué está pasando. Aunque apostaría por errores accediendo a rutas de assets como imágenes o algo así, pero lo dicho, esto es pura elucubración porque sin ver el error real, no se puede saber, podría ser cualquier cosa. Por cierto... esa dependencia que son solo tres unos (1), es correcta??

Si era el POM. Tenia que agregar el build y listo. Ya funciona perfectamente. Gracias!

Ya pude solucionarlo, debia agregar esto al POM:


<build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
           <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.mycompany.securetouch.SecureTouch</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
            <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
     
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>




Que agregaste especificamente para solucionar el problema.

el  ... el inicial y final

El contenido de tu archivo pom.xml no es el que tiene tu pregunta
